# javascript window mouseout event issue when mouse over on select/alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, alert, mouseout

I have a requirement, when user movesout of the browser window, I need to display a Exit PopUp. It was fine in Chrome and Mozilla. The problem was with the devil IE only. There is a registration form in the Page.

So in IE Below are the two issues I'm facing not able to figure it out.

1. when user trying to select the options of the select box this mouseout event triggering and Exit PopUp displaying
2. There is terms and conditions checkbox which will show you alert without checking it when user try to submit. When I clicks OK button on alert box the mouseout event triggering and showing my Exit PopUp.

How to avoid these two things. These issues are stopping the user from registering to our website.

Below is my code

```
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var mouseIsIn = true;
window.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
    if ((mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= window.innerHeight) && (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= window.innerWidth))
        return;

    document.getElementById("exitPop").style.display = 'block';
    mouseIsIn = false;

}, false);

window.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    if(mouseIsIn)
        return;

    mouseIsIn = true;
},false);
```

What are the changes I need to do to overcome those 2 issues?

jQuery solutions are also welcome.

**UPDATE**
Somehow I managed to fix the Selectbox issue by adding the following code

```
window.onmouseout = function(e){
inWin--;
setTimeout(function(){
    if(isIEbrowser) {
            if (e.toElement == null && e.relatedTarget == null)
               inWin--;

            if (e.srcElement !== undefined && e.srcElement.nodeName != undefined && (e.srcElement.nodeName == 'SELECT' || e.srcElement.nodeName == 'OPTION'))
                inWin=1;
        }

    if(inWin <=0)
    {       
            document.getElementById("exitPop").style.display = 'block';
        }
}, 100);}window.onmouseover = function(e){       inWin=1;}
```

But not able to fix the alertbox issue. Surprisingly this alertbox issue I'm facing both in IE and Firefox also.

Comment: What happened guys? nobody was responded....

Comment: Why this is happening? When I moving mouse inside the window the onmouseout event was firing.

window.onmouseout = function(e){
console.log("out of window");
};